# Sequelize need to associate an already existing record to newly created ones

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

i'm creating an app that stores many different types of objects,with their unique attributes stored in different tables, and an association to a table with general attributes shared by all the objects and that table has to be associated with a table storing already specified locations entered by the user.

I have created the tables and their associations already, an example of the code is here:
This is the general attribute table:

```
var AssetInfo = sequelize.define('AssetInfo', {
invoiceNumber: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
purchaseOrder: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
physicalCondition: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
modelName: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
supplier: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
manufacturer: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
status: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
purchaseCost: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:false},
acquiredDate: {type:Sequelize.DATE, allowNull:false},
lostOrStolen: {type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false, defaultValue:false},
lOSDate: {type:Sequelize.DATE, allowNull:true},
usefulLife: {type:Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull:true},
warrantyExpiry: {type:Sequelize.DATE, allowNull:false},
depreciateRate: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:false},
scrapped: {type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false, defaultValue:false},
dateScrapped: {type:Sequelize.DATE, allowNull:true},
scrappedTo: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:true},
sold: {type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false, defaultValue:false},
dateSold: {type:Sequelize.DATE, allowNull:true},
sellPrice: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:true},
priceLoss: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:true},
currentCost: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:false},
netRealisableValue: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:false},
fairValue: {type:Sequelize.DOUBLE, allowNull:false},
picture: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:true},
description: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:true}},
{freezeTableName:true}
);
```

This is one of the object tables and the location table:

```
var Computer = sequelize.define('Computer', {
serial: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
user: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false}},
{freezeTableName:true
});

var CompanyLocation = sequelize.define('CompanyLocation', {
companyName: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false},
site: {type:Sequelize.STRING, allowNull:false}},
{freezeTableName:true}
);

CompanyLocation.hasMany(AssetInfo);
Computer.hasMany(AssetInfo);
AssetInfo.belongsTo(Computer);
```

I was able to create the association to the object and the general info tables by:

```
function addComputer(inv, pur, phys, mod, sup, manu, stat, purC, acD, useLife,warr, dep, cur, netRe, fair, pic, desc, num, use){
sequelize.Promise.all([
    Computer.create({serial : num,user : use}),
    AssetInfo.create({invoiceNumber : inv, purchaseOrder: pur,
        physicalCondition : phys, modelName : mod, supplier : sup ,
        manufacturer : manu, status : stat, purchaseCost : purC,
        acquiredDate : acD, usefulLife : useLife, warrantyExpiry : warr,
        depreciateRate : dep, currentCost : cur, netRealisableValue : netRe,
        fairValue: fair, picture : pic, description : desc})
]).spread(function (comp, assIn) {
    return comp.addAssetInfo(assIn);
});
}
```

and have tried things like finding the premade location by name and trying to associated it with the newly created object and its general info table very unsuccessfully.

I couldn't find anything similar in the docs or other forums that could get the code to work, it just simply wouldn't associate them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to import the preset location into the original creation function like:

```
 function addComputer(inv, pur, phys, mod, sup, manu, stat, purC, acD, useLife,warr, dep, cur, netRe, fair, pic, desc, num, use){
sequelize.Promise.all([
    Computer.create({serial : num,user : use}),
    AssetInfo.create({invoiceNumber : inv, purchaseOrder: pur,
        physicalCondition : phys, modelName : mod, supplier : sup ,
        manufacturer : manu, status : stat, purchaseCost : purC,
        acquiredDate : acD, usefulLife : useLife, warrantyExpiry : warr,
        depreciateRate : dep, currentCost : cur, netRealisableValue : netRe,
        fairValue: fair, picture : pic, description : desc})
]).spread(function (comp, assIn) {
    return comp.addAssetInfo(assIn);
}).**Then(function(assIn)
   var locate = Location.findById(#);
   assIn.addLocation(locate));**
}
```

The seoond line was marked as unreachable text and wouldn't run

Then i trid making a seperate function to update them after creating both:

```
function addLocate(){
    var locate = Location.findById(#);
    var assIn = AssetInfo.findById(#);
    assIn.addLocation(locate);
}
```

that gave the error that assIn.addLocation was not a function (Also note i rewrote this code not copied directly, deleted the original since it didnt work so all syntax won't be exact, eg # was a number, addLocation was addCompanyLocation)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want? Do you need to associate a new AssetInfo with an existing Location? What have you tried? Which error do you get?

Comment: hey Jan, Yes i need to associate a new asset info with an existing location, ive tried(From code extract):  ... depreciateRate : dep, currentCost : cur, netRealisableValue : netRe,
        fairValue: fair, picture : pic, description : desc})
]).spread(function (comp, assIn) {
    return comp.addAssetInfo(assIn);
}).then(function(assIn){ var locate = location.findById(#);  assIn.addLocation(locate);

Comment: Then i tried creating both the assetinfo and location and afterwards retriving them and using varibles created by them to associate to each other like function(){ assetInfoVariable.addLocation(locationVariable);} (varibles declared first through var assetInfoVariable = assetInfo.findOne('By id'))

Comment: Please update your post instead - large code snippets in comments are unreadable :)

Comment: Sorry, first time posting on stack overflow, will remember thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findById` returns a promise, just like `create` does - you have to wait for the query to complete

```
function addComputer(inv, pur, phys, mod, sup, manu, stat, purC, acD, useLife, warr, dep, cur, netRe, fair, pic, desc, num, use) {
     sequelize.Promise.all([
         Computer.create({
             serial: num,
             user: use
         }),
         AssetInfo.create({
             invoiceNumber: inv,
             purchaseOrder: pur,
             physicalCondition: phys,
             modelName: mod,
             supplier: sup,
             manufacturer: manu,
             status: stat,
             purchaseCost: purC,
             acquiredDate: acD,
             usefulLife: useLife,
             warrantyExpiry: warr,
             depreciateRate: dep,
             currentCost: cur,
             netRealisableValue: netRe,
             fairValue: fair,
             picture: pic,
             description: desc
         })
     ]).spread(function(comp, assIn) {
         return comp.addAssetInfo(assIn);
     }).then(function(assIn) {
        return Location.findById(#).then(function (locate) {
            return assIn.addLocation(locate)); 
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hey Jan, Thank you for the answer, i'm trying to make it work now, i just have a question about the way that  then(function(assIn) would work. How does it know to create the assIn variable from the assetInfo that was created and not the computer that was created? (Kust for future reference)

Comment: You are right - actually comp.addAssetINfo returns comp. You can change it to `return comp.addAssetInfo(assIn).return(assIn);` https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#returndynamic-value---promise

Comment: So if I understand this correctly sequelize "maintains" a list of promise objects inside the function they are created/ called and are "assignable" in chronological order that they are created or called in?

Comment: Getting closer :). `create` returns a promise. `Promise.all` aggregates the two promises and waits until both are finished (resolved in promise terms). Once all promises are resolved, spread is called. spread takes an array, and 'spreads it out' into several arguments. If you had called `then` instead, you would get an array with two elements (the comp. and the assetinf). By using `spread` you get those as seperate arguments to the function

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks again for the help :)